# Pashley Pickle child's tricycle wheel rims to buy?

Tags: wheels, children, tricycle

Currently refurbishing a child's Pashley Pickle tricycle and need replacement wheel rims described in specs as 16" x 1 3/8" - anyone know where I can buy them or what type are needed please?

[image: ded]

Comment: Visiting your local bike shop with a sample rim is your best option.  Sadly this kind of question is a poor fit for this site, because its very localised, and is time-sensitive, and its really just shopping.

You'll need to match the spoke count too, which appears to be 28, and the rims will need a Schrader hole.

Also note that the rim's internal major diameter needs to be pretty close to the original, if you intend on reusing the existing spokes.

Comment: Wheels on children's bikes are often non-standard, though the ones in the picture look to be reasonably standard.  However, when I do a web search I find several different ISO diameters, and most are 32 hole.  Prices ranging from $17 to over $100 per rim.

Answer (score 1):

I edited the question so it wouldn't be a strictly sourcing/shopping question.

It appears these use the 16" size with bead seat diameter 349. Look carefully around the tires and old rims to try and find the number 349 to confirm. It will likely be on the tire and say something like "38-349". If you don't find it and find some other 3-digit number instead, that's also your answer.

Sometimes there's no such marking. If that's the case you can identify what BSD you're dealing with via measurement.

349 is the Brompton size. Rims for it are readily available but are a niche product you need to get from Brompton shops/dealers/etc. You also need to match spoke counts. Many or most Bromptons use 28h and it appears this trike also does.